# How to apply if and else angularjs controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have code in HTML

```
 <li><strong>Scrub:</strong> {{insuredProfile.permanentAddress.isScrubbed}}</li>
```

This show either true or false  i need to show Yes for true and No for false

If i use data-ng-if i can apply only one condition at a time. Can some one suggest better way to do it.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way would probably be using an inline if :

```
{{insuredProfile.permanentAddress.isScrubbed ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
```

Edited as per the comments, sorry for the typo.

Comment: What should i do for for False ?

Comment: Don't you mean 'No' instead of 'True'?

Comment: This contain one value at a time either True or False.For true i have to show Yes and for false i have to show No

Answer (score 2):

You could write a filter which does this

```
(function (app) {
    app.filter('boolToYesNo', function () {
        return function (input) {
            return input ? 'yes' : 'no';
        }
    });
})(angular.module('app'));
```

And then call it like

`{{ insuredProfile.permanentAddress.isScrubbed | boolToYesNo }}`